# How do I check if arguments are called to a vbscript?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, vbscript, arguments

I tried using an if statement but I got an error, `Subscript out of range`, I know why I got the error. How do I check if an argument(s) is called to a vbscript script.

```
if args.count > -1 then
  exec(args(0)) 'exec is a function that I defined. I know this is working.
  wscript.quit
end if
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
If WScript.Arguments.Count > 0 Then
  WScript.Echo "Arguments were passed"
End If

args = WScript.Arguments.Count
WScript.Echo "This many arguments were passed " & args
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if WScript.Arguments.Count > 0 Then
msgbox WScript.Arguments.item(0)
else 
msgbox "nothing was passed"
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**